# Classify values if any or the columns satisfy the condition & keep NA values

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I am trying to find out if any of my columns have a values overpassing certain value, e.g. 7. If yes, that classify it as `more`, otherwise be `less` . My problem is similar to question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572483/r-ifelse-find-if-any-column-meet-the-condition) but I can't figure out how to update it to my case. I need the values to be classified row-wise. Also, some of the rows can be filled in just by the NA/NaN values. I need to keep them in a dataframe, so I can't filter them before the calculation.

Example:

```
# Example: classify data if they fit the condition:
data <- data.frame(V1=c(1,5,7, NA),
                   V2=c(1,5,8, NA),
                   V3=c(3,9,10, NaN))


# Classify each column: 
ifelse(data$V1 >=7, "more", "less") 

# Classify based on all columns? NOT WORKING!
 data$NewCol <- +( Reduce(`|`, lapply(data, >=, 7)))
```

Desired outcome:

```
  V1 V2 V3 newCol
1  1  1  3 less   # no value is >= 7
2  5  5  9 more
3  7  8 10 more
4 NA NA NaN NA
```

Comment: Try `rowSums(data >= 7) > 0`, i.e. `ifelse(rowSums(data >= 7) > 0, 'more', 'less')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `rowSums` -

```
data$newCol <- ifelse(rowSums(data >= 7) > 0, 'more', 'less')
```

Or using `dplyr` with `case_when` if we have multiple conditions to check.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(newCol = case_when(all(is.na(c_across())) ~ NA_character_, 
                            any(c_across() >= 7) ~ 'more', 
                            TRUE ~ 'less'))

#     V1    V2    V3 newCol
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#1     1     1     3 less  
#2     5     5     9 more  
#3     7     8    10 more  
#4    NA    NA   NaN NA
```

Comment: HI @Ronak, thank you very much for the answer, it indeed work! One more question: and I have updated my example: how to handle if some rows consist only from NA/NaN values? Then they can be kept as NA, but I can't filter them first. Thank you again!

Comment: I have updated the `dplyr` answer to handle such a case.